# "Key does not exist" error in RSA asymmetric encryption decryption

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to implement an asymmetric cryptography approach using **RSA algorithm**
for that, I'm using the following class library from Microsoft [System.Security.Cryptography](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography?view=net-5.0)

[image: This image from Mashable]
*[This Image Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4HQ8Bp-pfw)*

so based on public-key sharing, This is my architecture

[image: ![enter image description here]

Basically, I've three standalone applications

1. Encryption/Decryption Service, which is a class library.
2. WPF Application to encrypt plain text to ciphertext.
3. Console Application to decrypt cipher text to plain text.

so this is my Encryption/Decryption Service Backbone

```
public class EncryptDecryptService : IEncryptDecryptService
{
    private static RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    private RSAParameters _privateKey;
    private RSAParameters _publicKey;

    public EncryptDecryptService()
    {
        _privateKey = csp.ExportParameters(true);
        _publicKey = csp.ExportParameters(false);
    }

    public void WritePrivateKey(string _privatePath)
    {
        TextWriter _privateKeyTxt = new StreamWriter(_privatePath);
        _privateKeyTxt.Write(GeneratePrivateKey());
        _privateKeyTxt.Close();
    }

    public void WritePublicKey(string _publicPath)
    {
        TextWriter _publicKeyTxt = new StreamWriter(_publicPath);
        _publicKeyTxt.Write(GeneratePublicKey());
        _publicKeyTxt.Close();
    }

    public string GeneratePublicKey()
    {
        var sw = new StringWriter();
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
        xs.Serialize(sw, _publicKey);
        return sw.ToString();
    }

    public string GeneratePrivateKey()
    {
        var sw = new StringWriter();
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
        xs.Serialize(sw, _privateKey);
        return sw.ToString();
    }
    public string EncryptText(string plainText, string wpfPrivateKeyPath, string consolePublicKeyPath)
    {
        csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();            

        var consoleAppPublicKey = CovertRSAXMLtoRSAParam(consolePublicKeyPath, false);
        var wpfAppPrivateKey = CovertRSAXMLtoRSAParam(wpfPrivateKeyPath, true);

        csp.ImportParameters(consoleAppPublicKey);
        csp.ImportParameters(wpfAppPrivateKey);

        var data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);// sample
        var cypher = csp.Encrypt(data, false);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(cypher);
    }
    public string DecryptText(string cypherText, string wpfPublicKeyPath, string consolePrivateKeyPath)
    {
        var dataBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cypherText);

        var consoleAppPrivateKey = CovertRSAXMLtoRSAParam(consolePrivateKeyPath, true);
        var wpfAppPublicKey = CovertRSAXMLtoRSAParam(wpfPublicKeyPath, false);

        csp.ImportParameters(consoleAppPrivateKey);
        csp.ImportParameters(wpfAppPublicKey);

        var plainText = csp.Decrypt(dataBytes, false);

        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainText);
    }
    public static RSAParameters CovertRSAXMLtoRSAParam(string _location, bool isExport)
    {
        string xmlContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(_location);
        RSAParameters _publicKey = new RSAParameters();
        CspParameters cspParam = new CspParameters();
        cspParam.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
        RSACryptoServiceProvider key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParam);
        key.FromXmlString(xmlContent);
        _publicKey = key.ExportParameters(isExport);
        return _publicKey;
    }

}
```

Like this way I'm generating the ciphertext for a plain text in WPF application

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var wpfPrivateKeyPath = "C:\\SERVICE\\keys\\wpf_private_key.txt";
        var consolePublicKeyPath = "C:\\SERVICE\\keys\\console_public_key.txt";
    
        objWebservice.WritePrivateKey(wpfPrivateKeyPath);
        objWebservice.WritePublicKey(consolePublicKeyPath);
        
        string _plainText = PlainTextValue.Text;
        string _encryptedText = objWebservice.EncryptText(_plainText, wpfPrivateKeyPath, consolePublicKeyPath);                
        EncryptedTextValue.Text = _encryptedText;
    }
```

Then that ciphertext I'm trying to convert back to previous plain text in the following way.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        EncryptDecryptService decryptService = new EncryptDecryptService();
        string encryptedText = "SDSFDSFSDFDSFSsdfsdf";

        var wpfPublicKeyPath = "C:\\SERVICE\\keys\\wpf_public_key.txt";
        var consolePrivateKeyPath = "C:\\SERVICE\\keys\\console_private_key.txt";

        decryptService.WritePrivateKey(consolePrivateKeyPath);
        decryptService.WritePublicKey(wpfPublicKeyPath);   
       
        var plaintText = decryptService.DecryptText(encryptedText, wpfPublicKeyPath, consolePrivateKeyPath);
        Console.WriteLine(plaintText);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

this is where an error occurring when it's going to decrypt as in this image.

[image]

what did I missed here, please if can guide me to make this correct :)

Comment: I think you managed to get absolutely everything about class design wrong here. I'm being left with so many questions that I don't know where to start. Um. Why is your `EncryptDecryptService` one service? Don't you need separate services as the sender generally doesn't have the private key? Why is your decryption application **writing keys**? Why is the service a static variable? Do you know it is dangerous to have static variables that are stateful?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thanks for replying to this, 

1. EncryptDecryptService one service?
- for this my intention was to implement a simpler version first then expand this. 
2. Don't you need separate s..?  - sender in the sense I think you meant wpf/console app I guess, this library generate private key automatically 
3. Why is your decryption application writing keys? - so when its store in EncryptDecryptService class library, when encrypt and decrypt happening, can access those private and public keys, 4. static- edited.  I would like to know the correct way If I'm going wrong direction

Comment: @MaartenBodewes as I understood here I try to implement `asymmetrical encryption using receiver public key + sender private key` then  `asymmetrical decryption using receiver private key + sender public key`

Comment: @Topaco I just updated based on suggestion, still have the same issue, can point where this going the wrong way :)

Comment: @Topaco I'm looking for this kind of solution actually, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.core.asymmetrickeyalgorithmprovider?view=winrt-20348

I'll try to make this work